# Baking a diffuse map replaces other image textures

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, uv, texture-baking

so i made an appartment with a bunch of materials, and i wanted to make it just one material.
It worked perfictly as expected, i added the image i was going to generate in every material like this (but the texture coordinate at generated);[image]

however when it was baked i wanted the textures with tiles to aling, so i put the texture coordintes on UV so i could that. then we i tried baking it again it just picked a random image in allmost every material.
How can i prevent that from happening?